# Автоматическое обновление Cell

Tags: c#, datagrid, wpf, binding

Добрый день.
У меня есть `DataGrid`

**XAML**

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgv1" ItemsSource="{Binding Elements}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Title" Binding="{Binding Title}" Width="250">
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Unit" Binding="{Binding Unit}" Width="75"/>
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Count" Binding="{Binding Count}" Width="75"/>
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Price" Binding="{Binding Price, TargetNullValue=N/A}" Width="75"/>
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Total Price" Binding="{Binding AllPrice}" Width="75"/>
</DataGrid>
```

**C#**

```
 public class Element : _Base
    {
        // Подчиненные элементы..
        private ObservableCollection<Element> _elements;
        public ObservableCollection<Element> Elements
        { get { return _elements; } set { _elements = value; } }

        // Скидки
        private ObservableCollection<Discount> _discounts;
        public ObservableCollection<Discount> Discounts
        { get { return _discounts; } set { _discounts = value; } }

        // Тоталы
        private ObservableCollection<Total> _totals;
        public ObservableCollection<Total> Totals
        { get { return _totals; } set { _totals = value; } }

        // Конструкторы...
        public Element()
        {
            _elements = new ObservableCollection<Element>();
            _discounts = new ObservableCollection<Discount>();
            _totals = new ObservableCollection<Total>();
        }

        public Element(string title, uint count = 1, decimal price = 0)
            :this()
        { _title = title; _count = count; _price = price; }

        // Название элемента
        private string _title = string.Empty;
        public string Title
        {
            get { return _title; }
            set
            {
                if (_title != value)
                {
                    _title = value;
                }
            }
        }

        // Кол-во
        private uint _count = 1;
        public uint Count
        {
            get { return _count; }
            set { if (_count != value) { _count = value; } }
        }

        // Цена за единицу
        private decimal _price;
        public decimal Price
        {
            get 
            {
                if (_price > 0)
                    return _price;
                else
                {
                    decimal res = 0;
                    foreach (var el in _elements)
                    {
                        res += el.Price * el._count;
                    }
                    return res;
                }
            }
            set
            {
                if (_price != value)
                {
                    _price = value;
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Общая стоимость (цена * кол-во)
        /// </summary>
        private decimal _allPrice;
        public decimal AllPrice
        {
            get 
            {
                if (_price > 0)
                {
                    return _price * _count;
                }
                else
                {
                    decimal res = 0;
                    foreach (var el in _elements)
                    {
                        res += el.Price * el._count;
                    }
                    return res * _count;
                }
            }
            set
            {
                ;
            }

        }

        //public event MyPropertyChanged PropertyChanged;
    }
```

В итоге на форме я вижу `DataGrid` с пятью столбцами.
При изменении данных в столбцах 3 и 4 (`Count` и `Price` соответственно) я хочу, чтобы я пятом столбце (`AllPrice`) данные обновлялись, но этого не происходит...
Насильственно изменить ячейку, как в `WinForms` с `DataGridView` (`UpdateCellValue(4, dgvMain.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex)`), возможности нет - точнее, я не нашел оную.

Наследование от интерфейса `INotifyPropertyChanged` и подписка на событие изменения мне не помогла... 
В привязывании (`Binding`) с WPF я абсолютно не был знаком до сегодняшнего дня.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, ошибка в моей модели? Я не правильно привязываю?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Наследование от интерфейса INotifyPropertyChanged и подписка на событие изменения мне не помогла

Должна была. Наследуйтесь от него и при изменении `Count` и `Price`. Генерите событие изменения не только для них, но и для `AllPrice`. Вот пример для `Count`:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

// Обертка над `PropertyChanged`
private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
   if (PropertyChanged == null)
      return;
   PropertyChanged(this, new new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}

public uint Count
{
   get { return _count; }
   set 
   { 
      if (_count == value)
        return;
      _count = value;
      RaisePropertyChanged("Count"); // Для текущего поля
      RaisePropertyChanged("AllPrice"); // Сообщаем об изменении и этого поля тоже
   }
}
```

Comment: to > Donil
Спасибо большое!
По своей глупости, вместо
   PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
писал
   PropertyChanged(propertyName, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
Еще раз большое спасибо!

Comment: Пожалуйста!)